# Odin doesn't recognize Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, custom-roms, odin

While I was trying to flash my phone to newer version of custom mod, I bricked my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 for Verizon, SCH-I535). To debrick the phone, I've followed below precedure:

1. Confirm USB cable is not faulty.
2. Confirm my MicroSD is not faulty.
3. Format MicroSD to FAT32, then image Verizon Stock firmware through Win32 Imager.
4. Enter into "Download" mode on the phone.
5. Confirm my Windows 7 system recognizes the phone. To do so, I confirmed the phone enters into "USB Debugging mode". Window7 recognizes the phone as "MSM8960".
6. Confirm `adb` works and recognizes the devices.

Then, I ran Odin3 (v3.09) to see if Odin recognizes the phone, but no luck here.

What are some reasons Odin isn't recognizing my phone? What are some other alternative way I can debrick the phone (other than flashing the ROM through Odin)?

Comment: Try Odin 3.04 it seems better, try a different USB port or PC. Failing that you could copy a ROM onto your SD card and just install that through recovery?

Comment: It's not USB or PC problem (I've tried in different ports on different PCs). I'm able to copy ROM to SD card. And, yes, recovery is successfully installed on SD card, and I can tell this by confirming the phone is booted to recovery mode only if SD card is inserted. I'll try different version of Odin.